# Simple Short JQuery and DataFetch Test Return Error

Tags: javascript

Simple Short JQuery and DataFetch Test Return Error

I used the following code at 2 files

1.php

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="css/dailog.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/calendar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
    <link href="css/dp.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />   
    <link href="css/alert.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 

    <script src="src/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  

  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        var DATA_FEED_URL =  "2.php";

        var param = [{ "name": "eventId", value: 9}];                

        $.post(DATA_FEED_URL,
               param,
               function(data){
                 if(data.IsSuccess){
                   alert(data.Msg)
                   //CloseModelWindow(null,true);                            
                 } else {
                   alert("Error occurs.\r\n" + data.Msg);
                 }
        }
        ,"json");
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and below is my

2.php

```
$eventSend = $_POST['eventId'];

$ret="fail";


if(isset($eventSend)){
   getTest($_POST['eventId']);
}

function getTest($eventId) {
   $ret = "Hello";
}

echo json_encode($ret);
```

I get an error message in alert box

```
Error occurs. undefined
```

What should I do, i just want to test basic jquery post between 2 pages.
but the result was error even I fixed the response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the .done() callback

```
$.post(DATA_FEED_URL,
       param
    )
   .done(function( data ) {
       alert( "Data Loaded: " + data ); 
   });
```

I've taken this snippet from the jQuery website http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

EDIT:
Try using Ajax... When I need post request I usually do somenthing like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "request.php",
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    dataType: "JSON",
    data: {mdata:jsonstring}
}).success(function(e){

    if(e.Status == "OK"){
        alert("Server said it was fine");
    }else{
        alert("Server said it failed");
    }
}).fail(function(e){
   alert(failed to send request);
});
```

And in PHP

```
<?php //request.php file
    $data = json_decode($_POST['mdata'],true);

    if(your_condition)
        echo json_encode(array('Status' => 'OK'));
    else
        echo json_encode(array('Status' => 'KO',
                               'Reason'=> 'your_reason'));
?>
```

Comment: It should alert you wether it succeed or fail sending data to the url..

That's strange

Comment: I've edited the answer with another example.. check it out if it could help

Comment: still nothing? try using the debugger of your web browser (I suggest Firefox)... place some breakpoint and see where the problem is